# How to pass id in self.env odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In 'products.template' table I created three fields width,length and gsm. Now I want to retrieve it in 'mrp' table.First I will get the ids from mrp bill of materials and assign it to a variable called prod. 'mrp.bom.line' table contains product id.So through iterator I want to pass id of product stored in mrp bill of materials table to retrieve the value of width,length and gsm stored in product.template table.I am getting error as `programming error can't adapt type 'product.product'`.

```
@api.multi
def _compute_rim_weight(self):
    bill_of_materials_id=[1,2,3]
    prod = self.env['mrp.bom.line'].browse(bill_of_materials_id)
    for i in prod:
            j = self.env['product.template'].browse(i.product_id)
            self.rim_weight = (j.width * j.length * j.gsm)/20000        
    return self.rim_weight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In ODOO browse take **id** not **object**

so just replace  browse(i.**product_id**)  with browse(i.**product_id.id**) as below:

```
j = self.env['product.template'].browse(i.product_id.id)
```

One more thing if in case  `product.template`  have** many2one relation**  with `model :mrp.bom.line` from my understanding you even don't need the call browse .

Directly  call **line.product_id.width** ,**line.product_id.length**,**line.product_id.gsm** as below :

```
@api.multi
def _compute_rim_weight(self):
    bill_of_materials_ids=[1,2,3]
    bom_lines = self.env['mrp.bom.line'].browse(bill_of_materials_ids)
    for line in bom_lines:            
            self.rim_weight = (line.product_id.width * line.product_id.length * line.product_id.gsm)/20000        
    return self.rim_weight


@api.one
def _compute_rim_weight(self):
    rim_weight   =0
    for line in self.bom_id.bom_line_ids:            
            rim_weight+ = (line.product_id.width * line.product_id.length * line.product_id.gsm)/20000        
    self.rim_weight =rim_weight
```

Comment: In the first line I am hard-coding bill of materials id how to automate it using self.env.I want to pass BOM id to the seond line of this function

Comment: _compute_rim_weight weight is in  mrp.bom.line ?? if yes then just use "for line in self "

Comment: Not weight I want to pass BOM id(1,2,3) to the second line.for id 1 product id is 4 and so on

Comment: browse() method accepts ids,so I want to avoid hard-coding BOM ids like (1,2,3) and passing it to browse()

Comment: as _compute_rim_weight id decorated with @pi.multi  so if in case _compute_rim_weight weight is in mrp.bom.line , we don't need to use browse , we can just iterate over self as self also contain the list of object of model (if the method is decorated with @api.multi), hope you get waht i want to say , just confirm me that method compute_rim_weight weight is in the model  mrp.bom.line

Comment: This function is written in ''mrp.production" class not in "mrp.bom.line" thats the problem

Comment: AS mrp.production have m21 with mrp.bom:bom_id and mrp.bom  have 12m with mrp.bom.line:bom_line_ids   , so you can use self.bom_id.bom_line_ids  , i have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try